# CUDA 6.0 Linking error: undefined reference to `__cudaUnregisterFatBinary'

Tags: c++, eclipse, cuda, nvcc

I am trying to compile a simple CUDA program in Eclipse.

```
g++ -L/opt/cuda/lib64 -o "cuda_esn" ./cu_cuda_test.o ./main.o -lcuda -lstdc++
```

As you can see I am linking `-lcuda` and set the library path `-L/opt/cuda/lib64`. But unfortunately I have no idea why this is not compiling.

Complete output:

```
18:36:35 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project cuda_esn ****
make all 
Building file: ../cuda_test.cu
Invoking: CUDA NVCC Compiler
nvcc -c  -o "cu_cuda_test.o" "../cuda_test.cu" && \
echo -n 'cu_cuda_test.d' ./ > 'cu_cuda_test.d' && \
nvcc -M   "../cuda_test.cu" >> 'cu_cuda_test.d'
nvcc warning : The 'compute_10' and 'sm_10' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.
nvcc warning : The 'compute_10' and 'sm_10' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.
Finished building: ../cuda_test.cu

Building target: cuda_esn
Invoking: C++ Linker
g++ -L/opt/cuda/lib64 -o "cuda_esn"  ./cu_cuda_test.o ./main.o   -lcuda -lstdc++
./cu_cuda_test.o: In function `__cudaUnregisterBinaryUtil()':
makefile:32: recipe for target 'cuda_esn' failed
tmpxft_00001041_00000000-3_cuda_test.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `__cudaUnregisterFatBinary'
./cu_cuda_test.o: In function `__nv_init_managed_rt_with_module(void**)':
tmpxft_00001041_00000000-3_cuda_test.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to `__cudaInitModule'
./cu_cuda_test.o: In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll_44_tmpxft_00001041_00000000_6_cuda_test_cpp1_ii_aeee46d9()':
tmpxft_00001041_00000000-3_cuda_test.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x9c): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterFatBinary'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [cuda_esn] Error 1
```

---

This would be the source code (not really exciting yet):

cuda_test.h

```
#ifndef CUDARR
#define CUDARR

#ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C"
#endif

void foo_wrapper();

#endif
```

cuda_test.cu

```
#include "cuda_test.h"
#include "cuda.h"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"

extern "C" void foo_wrapper()
{
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cuda_test.h"

int main() {

  std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;

  foo_wrapper();

  return 0;
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you need to link to `cudart`, cuda runtime, as well.  Add `-lcudart`

Comment: I feel stupid. I did this already but all the time I linked either `cuda` or `cudart` but never both at once O_o .. thank you, it works now (have to wait four minutes to accept the answer)

Comment: @StefanR.Falk if i had a dollar for each time i asked an obvious question I'd buy Bill Gates.

Comment: I know that feeling. No one pays me either for that :D